# GWT UiConstructor with arguments, class has no appropriate setter method

Tags: xml, gwt, layout, constructor, uibinder

I'd like to implement a custom TabLayoutPanel which would automatically setup the tab itself when adding a widget (with custom actions such as closing the tab, etc).

I created a CustomTabPanel.ui.xml along with a CustomTabPanel.java. The UI design simply embeds a TabLayoutPanel and the code part exposes some functions that I need.
I also have a constructor that takes the same 2 arguments as the TabLayoutPanel, that I would like to pass in UI design mode just as I do with the plain TabLayoutPanel.
It looks like this

```
public class CustomTabPanel extends Composite{
    /* ... here all the uiBinder things
       already written by my eclipse plugin */

    @UiField(provided=true)
    TabLayoutPanel tabPanel;

    public @UiConstructor CustomTabPanel(double barHeight, Unit barUnit){
        tabPanel = new TabLayoutPanl(barHeight, barUnit);
        initWidget(uiBinder.creatAndBindUi(this));
    }
```

I use the custom composite widget in another `.ui.xml` file
But then, when I launch and test the web app in my browser, I get the following error:

> Class CustomTabPanel has no appropriate setBarUnit() method.
>    Element <my:ClosableTabPanel barHeight='2' barUnit='EM' ui:field='closablepanel'>

I followed the instructions read on http://code.google.com/intl/fr/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html#Using_a_widget to make this. I think I have missed something but I can't find out what it is.

Also I tried before to use inheritance by creating a derived `class ExtendedTabLayoutPanel extends TabLayoutPanel{...}` and implementing the constructor with the arguments. This gives me, at runtime, another error :

> Line xx: Type mismatch: cannot convert from TabLayoutPanel to ExtendedTabLayoutPanel

Hope I'm clear enough... Read you soon!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was having the same problem. It turns out that the order of the arguments is important somehow; see http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=5272

When you have the order right, you don't need to worry about converting the enum. I now have this:

```
public @UiConstructor FancyTabLayoutPanel(Unit barUnit, double barHeight) {...}
```

... and in my .ui.xml file:

```
<v:FancyTabLayoutPanel barUnit="EM" barHeight="2.0"></v:FancyTabLayoutPanel>
```

I wonder if the required order of arguments is robust across different deployments?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue might have to do with the fact that com.google.gwt.dom.client.Style.Unit is an enumeration. An alternative approach that should solve the problem is to change barUnit to type string and then use Unit.valueOf(barUnit) to retrieve the appropriate enumeration value. This also give you the ability to properly error check the unit name being passed.

As for the issue with inheritance in UiBinder this is actually a [known issue](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=4342) that has been patched but hasn't been officially added to GWT.

Comment: Even with unit passed as String, the error remains. Though, it works fine when passed as Unit or String, but as the FIRST argument. Seems that it matches the bug z0r told about.